# How to update a record using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to update the records form a table by using Sequelize. 
Unfortunately, the id of the event I am trying to update seems to be undefined. How can I send it correctly?

The block of code I have in my controller looks like this:

```
router.get('/edit/:eventid', function(req, res) {
    var eventid = req.params.eventid;
    Event.findById(req.params.eventid).then(function(event) {
        eventid= event.eventid;
        title= event.title;
        description= event.description;     
        availabletickets=event.availabletickets;
        date= event.date;        
        newDate= date.toString();
        newdate= newDate.substring(0,21);

         console.log(eventid);
        }) .then(function() {
            res.render('eventEdit', {
                eventid: eventid, 
                pagetitle: ' Edit Event',
                title: title,
                description:description,
                availabletickets:availabletickets,
                newdate: newdate,              
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            res.render('error', {
                error: error
            });
        });       
});

router.post('/edit', function(req, res){
   var eventid = req.body.eventid;
   var title = req.body.title;    
   var description = req.body.description;
   var availabletickets= req.body.availabletickets;
   var date = req.body.date;
  console.log( eventid); //this returns undefined.
  console.log('title, description, availabletickets, date);

  const newData = {  
     title: title,
       date: date,
       description: description,
       availabletickets: availabletickets
  };

    Event.update(
    newData,
      {    
      where:{
        eventid:eventid
        }
       }
  ).then(function() {
         console.log("Event updated");
        res.redirect('/events');
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));

});
```

Although, the HTML file,where the user introduces the values when editing the events, looks like this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <h2><%= pagetitle %> </h2>

  <form method="post" action="/events/edit"> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<%= title %>"  placeholder="Titlu Eveniment" required="true"> 
              <p style="color:#8B0000;"><small>*This field is mandatory</small></p>
              <textarea  rows=7 class="form-control" type="text"  name="description"  id="description"  placeholder="Descriere Eveniment"><%= description %></textarea> <br>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="availabletickets" id="availabletickets"  value="<%= availabletickets %>"> <br>
            <label> Data:<%= newdate %> </label> <br/>
                          <label>Cahnge event date:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" id="date" style="width:190px;" ><br> 

               <button class="btn" id="addValue" style="background-color:#8B0000; color:white;">Save</button>&nbsp; 
               <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: action="/events/edit" in html but your api route is /edit

Comment: @AsifSaeed Probably that router is namespaced by another router (`/events`).

Comment: @IonicăBizău there is n submit in html aswell right? plus there is no tag to hold eventid which needs to be passed maybe there should be a hidden tag

Comment: @AsifSaeed The `<button>` is enough to handle the form submit (I guess it even works without a submit button at all). You're right about the input holding the `eventid`. Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `eventid` as `undefined`  because `req.body` doesn't contain the `eventid` (it's not passed from the client side). To pass it from the client side you have to add an input having the `name="eventid"` attribute.

In the EJS template you need to render the `eventid` value as a `hidden` input (`<input type="hidden" ...`)

You can do that by added in your form this line:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= eventid %>" name="eventid" />
```

This is the updated form code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2><%= pagetitle %> </h2>

  <form method="post" action="/events/edit">
    <input type="hidden" value="<%= eventid %>" name="eventid" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<%= title %>" placeholder="Titlu Eveniment" required="true">
            <p style="color:#8B0000;"><small>*This field is mandatory</small></p>
            <textarea rows=7 class="form-control" type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descriere Eveniment">
              <%= description %>
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="availabletickets" id="availabletickets" value="<%= availabletickets %>">
            <br>
            <label> Data:
              <%= newdate %>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label>Cahnge event date:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" id="date" style="width:190px;">
            <br>

            <button class="btn" id="addValue" style="background-color:#8B0000; color:white;">Save</button>&nbsp;
            <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```